# Function works perfectly on certain tabs/sheets, but not on others

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, foreach

My Goal: Be able to run the script from any tab/sheet. The script is attempting to collect data at the column where my named range "RepPrTracking" exists in each 'Week' tab. It then places said data in the 'Rep PR Data' tab.

Key Issue: The script works as intended when I have one of my 'Week' tabs open. However, when I'm on any other tab, I get:
*Error Exception: Range Not Found @ line 5*. The variable in line 5 references a named range in my tabs called Week 1, Week 2, etc., which leads me to believe that the script is running on whichever tab I have open, and not only on the weekly tabs.

I feel like the fix here is relatively simple, but I just can't seem to crack it. I'm really new to loops of any kind. Any and all help is very appreciated.

Edit: When I swap out the tableCol variable with column 80, it works exactly as intended, without any issues.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1244w0mAmnkAfmOdfk2mbcnraJdJK7Pah3uzqeiQh3E4/edit?usp=sharing

```
function createMaxList() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const target = ss.getSheetByName('Rep PR Data');
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const tableCol = ss.getRange("RepPrTracking").getColumn(); //dynamically references the table header in the weekly tabs
  const results = [['Week', 'Exercise', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10','e1RM']];

  sheets.forEach(s => { 
    const name = s.getName() //Name of every tab in the spreadsheet
    if (!name.match(/Week[\s\S]\d/)) {

      return;
    }

    s.getRange(3, tableCol, s.getLastRow() - 2, 12).getValues()
      .forEach((row) => {
        const [exc] = row
        if (exc == "" || exc == "Reps:" || !exc) {
          return;
        }
        results.push([name, ...row])
      })
  })

  target.getDataRange().clearContent() //clears 'Rep PR Data' tab
  target.getRange(1, 1, results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results) //places data in 'Rep PR Data'

}
```

Comment: There is a range `RepPrTracking` on each of Week1, Week2, etc.  When you are not on one of those tabs, which Week should it use?

Comment: Hi James, I'd like it to collect data from all the tabs that include "Week" in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, a named range of "RepPrTracking" is set in multiple sheets. In this case, when `const tableCol = ss.getRange("RepPrTracking").getColumn();` is run, and the range of the active sheet is checked. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. If you want to remove this issue, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function createMaxList() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const target = ss.getSheetByName('Rep PR Data');
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const results = [['Week', 'Exercise', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'e1RM']];
  sheets.forEach(s => {
    const name = s.getName();
    if (!name.match(/Week[\s\S]\d/)) {
      return;
    }

    const tableCol = s.getRange("RepPrTracking").getColumn(); // <-- Moved here.

    s.getRange(3, tableCol, s.getLastRow() - 2, 12).getValues()
      .forEach((row) => {
        const [exc] = row
        if (exc == "" || exc == "Reps:" || !exc) {
          return;
        }
        results.push([name, ...row]);
      })
  })
  target.getDataRange().clearContent();
  target.getRange(1, 1, results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your other part works in your script. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you for responding. When moving the variable to that location, I now get 2 errors: 
Exception: Range not found
(anonymous) @ Max.gs:17
createMaxList @ Max.gs:8

Comment: My apologies Tanaike, I didn't realize you changed **ss. to s.** with the moved variable, and that solved it! Once again, after hours of debugging, you've come to my rescue. I can't thank you enough!